# Aliases with correlated subqueries

Tags: postgresql, subquery, alias

I am looking at an example of correlated subquery with aliases from a PostgreSQL book:

```
bpsimple=# SELECT * FROM orderinfo o,
bpsimple=# (SELECT * FROM customer c WHERE town = 'Bingham') c
bpsimple=# WHERE c.customer_id = o.customer_id;
```

Why is the `c` alias used twice here? Isn't the one inside the parenthesis enough?

Comment: No, the one inside the parenthesis is redundant. The one outside the parenthesis is the alias for the derived table and is enough.

Comment: c as an alias for customer is overwritten by c as alias for customer where town ='Bingham' so they are not the same.

Comment: And it's not a correlated subquery, it's an (uncorrelated) subquery. Usually called a "derived table".

Comment: It is not required here, though it does not harm. If the inner query were more complicated then having something aliased to `c` inside and the overall derived table referred to as `c` too causes potential confusion (like this) so should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@ypercube already explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61449/aliases-with-correlated-subqueries#comment110557_61449), the subquery has no reference to columns in the outer query, it can be processed independently. So it is not a "correlated subquery". Some call that a "derived table", or just "subquery".

```
SELECT *
FROM   orderinfo o
    , (SELECT * FROM customer c1 WHERE town = 'Bingham') c2
WHERE  c2.customer_id = o.customer_id;
```

As to your questions:

- `c1` is a table alias for `customer` in the subquery, short for `customer AS c1`. The key word `AS` has been omitted which is fine since it would be just noise for a *table* alias. I quote the manual on ["Omitting the AS Key Word"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61449/aliases-with-correlated-subqueries#comment110557_61449):

  > In `FROM` items, both the standard and PostgreSQL allow `AS` to be omitted
  >   before an alias that is an unreserved keyword. But this is **impractical
  >   for output column names, because of syntactic ambiguities**.

  The example probably goes to demonstrate visibility: only the outer table alias is visible in the outer `WHERE` clause, so there is no naming conflict with `c` used twice.
  Otherwise, `c1` is useless here since nothing refers to it. You can just drop it.
- `c2` is another table alias for the "derived table". This one is mandatory since Postgres requires a name for every used table, and a subquery has none until you name it.

The **example is not very good overall**. Such a query should rather use an explicit JOIN clause and the subquery is just useless. This would be better, shorter and faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM   orderinfo
JOIN   customer  c USING (customer_id)
WHERE  c.town = 'Bingham';
```

The only difference: `customer_id` is listed *once* instead of twice in the result (due to the `USING` clause), which would be preferable since it is completely redundant in this case.

Details in the [manual about `SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html).