# How to remove object from json array?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, json

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR,
    images json
);
```

images format:

```
[
  {
    "id": "owner",
    "full": "<url>",
    "thumb": "<url>"
  },
  {
    "id": "note_0",
    "full": "<url>",
    "thumb": "<url>"
  },
  {
    "id": "note_1",
    "full": "<url>",
    "thumb": "<url>"
  },
  {
    "id": "note_2",
    "full": "<url>",
    "thumb": "<url>"
  }
]
```

I need something like this:

```
UPDATE items SET images = delete(images, 'note_1');
```

Comment: Please be more specific: do you mean `'{"id":"note_1"}'` or delete any element from the array that has `'note_1'` as key *or* value?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, delete `{"id": "note_1", "full": "<url>", "thumb": "<url>"}` where id = "note_1"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remove all elements from the column `images` (holding a json array) where `'id'` is `'note_1'`:

### pg 9.3

```
UPDATE items i
SET    images = i2.images
FROM  (
  SELECT id, array_to_json(array_agg(elem)) AS images
  FROM   items i2
       , json_array_elements(i2.images) elem
  WHERE  elem->>'id' <> 'note_1'
  GROUP  BY 1
  ) i2
WHERE  i2.id = i.id
AND    json_array_length(i2.images) < json_array_length(i.images);
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a09e9/14)

#### Explain

1. Unnest the JSON array with `json_array_elements()` in a subquery using an implicit `JOIN LATERAL` for the set-returning function. Details:

   - [PostgreSQL joining using JSONB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83932/postgresql-joining-using-jsonb/83935#83935)
   - [How to turn json array into postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)
2. JOIN to the base table and add another `WHERE` condition using `json_array_length()` to exclude unaffected rows - so you don't update each and every row of the table, which would be expensive (and wide-spread) nonsense.

### pg 9.4

This gets much easier with `jsonb` and [**additional `jsonb` operators**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE).

```
UPDATE items i
SET    images = i2.images
FROM  (
  SELECT id, array_to_json(array_agg(elem)) AS images
  FROM   items cand
       , json_array_elements(cand.images) elem
  WHERE  cand.images @> '{[{"id":"note_1"}]}'::jsonb
  AND    elem->>'id' <> 'note_1'
  GROUP  BY 1
  ) i2
WHERE i2.id = i.id;
```

Eliminates unaffected rows at the start, which is ***much faster***. Plus, there is [**extensive native index support**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) for `jsonb`, too, now.

Here are some example, benchmarks and comparison of new features to old json and MongoDB,  plus outlook to [jsquery](https://github.com/akorotkov/jsquery) by (some of) their main authors, Alexander Korotkov, Oleg Bartunov andTeodor Sigaevat PGCon 2014:

- ["CREATE INDEX ... USING VODKA"](http://www.pgcon.org/2014/schedule/events/696.en.html)

Comment: what does items cand mean

Comment: @commonSenseCode: `FROM items cand` is short syntax for `FROM items AS cand` - `cand` is a table alias. The `AS` keyword is safe to omit for *table* aliases (as opposed to column aliases). See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61455/3684 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543614/939860

Comment: yer a wizard Erwin

Comment: The 9.3 version (at least) doesn't appear to work if you're removing the last item from an array?