# Is it possible to select distinct values in a json document using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, json, greatest-n-per-group

I have a column that is using the JSON type. I would like to perform a query to select all distinct records for a particular field in the JSON string: I.e. given these three documents

```
{
  id: 1,
  s: "foo"
},
{
  id:2,
  s: "bar"
},
{
  id:3,
  s: "foo"
},
```

the query must check the "s" key for distinct values and return the documents with id 1 and 2.

Comment: Please provide a proper example with valid syntax, your version of Postgres, the table definition and what you have tried - even if it's not working.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter sorry about that, you are right. Thing is I don't actually have anything ready, I'm evaluating switching from MongoDB to PostgreSQL and I need to make sure that I can translate a distinct query in MongoDB to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Here's an additional postgresql JSON question you might find interesting: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/281480/45101

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming a **JSON array** in a Postgres **9.4** [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) column, this would do the job:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (doc->'s') doc
FROM  (
   SELECT '[
    {
      "id":1,
      "s":"foo"
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "s":"bar"
    },
    {
      "id":3,
      "s":"foo"
    }]'::jsonb AS j
   ) t
   , jsonb_array_elements(t.j) WITH ORDINALITY t1(doc, rn)
ORDER  BY doc->'s', rn;
```

Or, unless `s` is a nested object, it's probably cheaper to fold on the `text` *value* instead of the `jsonb` (sub-)record. Just use the [operator  `->>` instead of `->`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) in this case. The result is the same:

```
 doc
----------------------
'{"s": "bar", "id": 2}'
'{"s": "foo", "id": 1}'
```

Replace the subquery `t` with your actual table.

Key elements are [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) (or `json_array_elements()`) in a `LATERAL` join with `WITH ORDINALITY` and then the Postgres-specific `DISTINCT ON`.

Related, with more explanation:

- [How to remove object from json array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84472/how-to-remove-object-from-json-array/84495#84495)
- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)
- [How to preserve the original order of elements in an unnested array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-preserve-the-original-order-of-elements-in-an-unnested-array/27287#27287)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)